# EntityFramework. Fluent Api. Invert mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have the following classes:

```
class Parent
{
    public int ID;
    public Child Child1;
    public Child Child2;
}

class Child
{
    public int ID;
    public string Data;
}
```

Using DbModelBuilder I have the following Fluent API code:

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent> adrInEgrul 
    = modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>();
adrInEgrul.HasKey(x => x.ID);
adrInEgrul.HasOptional(x => x.Child1)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
adrInEgrul.HasOptional(x => x.Child2)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

All this gives me the following tables:
[image]

But I do need the following ones:
[image]

I'll be happy to get what I want just fixing Fluent API part, but have no Idea how to do it (if it's possible at all).
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Just add the `public int Child1Id {get;set;}` and one for the second to the parent! And remove the fluent code

Answer (score 0):

After comment of callum-linington I came up with the following Fluent API code, which did the work.

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent> adrInEgrul 
    = modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>();
adrInEgrul.HasKey(x => x.ID);
adrInEgrul.HasOptional(x => x.Child1);
adrInEgrul.HasOptional(x => x.Child2);
```